# How to Build a multi-panel User Interface in Android?

Tags: android, interface

For My Android Application I need to design multi-panel User Interface, Like with android sdk 
3.o newest version they provide a new Concept of FRAGMENT but our Android Board is running with sdk 2.3 version, I am Continuously searching to get this fragment thing by any other way , we need to design same fragment like design for Activity with sdk 2.3 API level-8,

I didnt get any way to do this,Like I am using TAB layout but it is from my side ,not much more comfortable.

Please give me some solution to get it

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how soon you need this done, you might want to wait for the fragment SDK to be released by Google. They've said that fragments are fairly easy to package up for inclusion in older versions of Android. They said "soon". Unfortunately, there's really no way to know when "soon" is.

Comment: Thanks Dave But My question is that How we get this fragment like design with older SDK. Isnt any way to design this with available facility of sdk2.2 API level 8.

Comment: The fragment SDK got released yesterday so you should be able to go use that now. I wouldn't want to try to figure out another way to do what you want to do.

Comment: like Dave I have Design TABS for my Application And i am easily change the orientation of TABs Top to Bottom but I am trying to get these TABs at left side of Screen so that I will utilize moe screen space as Device have a 7 inch big screen during that R&D i am gone through this fragment concept. If u give me som guidr how to get this Tab orientation on Left side of Screen or any other Design technique is available...I am waitink for some response.